# Jquery: get value of closest button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here its my html code

```
<div class="panel-footer">
<div class="input-group">
<input id="btn-input" class="form-control input-sm chat_input message" type="text" placeholder="Write your message here..." ng-model="messageToSend">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button id="btn_chat" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_chat" value="79">Send</button>
</span>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
<input id="btn-input" class="form-control input-sm chat_input message" type="text" placeholder="Write your message here..." ng-model="messageToSend">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button id="btn_chat" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_chat" value="80">Send</button>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

And here its my jquery code

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.message', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
    var msg = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).closest('span').next('button.btn_chat').val();
    alert(msg);
    alert(id);
}
e.preventDefault();
});
```

stuck on id it shows always undefine.

how can I get button value

Comment: your `button` and `input` tags has a same id?

Answer (score 1):

I have inserted code. here it is with id not giving undefined

```js
$(document).on('keypress', '.message', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
    var msg = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).next('span').find('button.btn_chat').val();
    alert(msg);
    alert(id);
}
e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-footer">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="btn-input" class="form-control input-sm chat_input message" type="text" placeholder="Write your message here..." ng-model="messageToSend">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
<button id="btn_chat" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_chat" value="79">Send</button>
</span>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="btn-input" class="form-control input-sm chat_input message" type="text" placeholder="Write your message here..." ng-model="messageToSend">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
<button id="btn_chat" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_chat" value="80">Send</button>
</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the span is the next sibling and the button is a descendant of the span so using [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest) and [next](https://api.jquery.com/next) will not work.

The [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest) is used to find a ancestor element and [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next) to find the next sibling element.

In your case you should use [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next) to find the span and use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find) to find the descendant button

```
var id = $(this).next('span').find('button.btn_chat').val();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5beyp755/)

---

Another easier solution is to use a `data-*` attribute to store the value in the input element itself like

```
<input id="btn-input" class="form-control input-sm chat_input message" type="text" placeholder="Write your message here..." ng-model="messageToSend" data-id="79">
```

then

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).closest('span')` will search for the nearest parent span tag of the text box, instead you need adjacent span tag. Try using `next()` with `find()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input:text.message').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (13 !== e.which) return;
    var btn = $(this).next().find('.btn_chat');
    console.log(this.value, btn.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-footer">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="btn-input" class="form-control input-sm chat_input message" type="text" placeholder="Write your message here..." ng-model="messageToSend">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
<button id="btn_chat" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_chat" value="79">Send</button>
</span>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="btn-input" class="form-control input-sm chat_input message" type="text" placeholder="Write your message here..." ng-model="messageToSend">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
<button id="btn_chat" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_chat" value="80">Send</button>
</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using $(this).parent().closest('span').next('button.btn_chat').val();